# How to get drag and drop working with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am having persistent problem on getting the drag and drop functionality working with Selenium WebDriver.

According the WebDriver documentation the drag/drop should work out of the box with command:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("source"));
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.name("target"));
(new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element, target).perform();
```

However this seems not to be working either with Firefox or Chrome driver.

Below is an example test that tries to use drag and drop functionality on 2 public draggable web sites. Test is parameterized and executed with both FirefoxDriver and ChromeDriver.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class DragAndDropTest {

    enum Browser {FIREFOX, CHROME};

    private Browser browser;
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() throws Exception {
        List<Object[]> params = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        params.add(new Object[] { Browser.FIREFOX });
        params.add(new Object[] { Browser.CHROME });
        return params;
    }

    public DragAndDropTest(Browser browser) {
        this.browser = browser;
    }

    @Before
    public void before() {
        switch (browser) {
        case FIREFOX:
            this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            break;
        case CHROME:
            this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        By drag = By.id("div1");
        By drop = By.id("div2");
        By expected = By.cssSelector("#div2 #drag1");
        // load page
        driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp");
        // wait for draggable element visible
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(drag));
        // drag and drop
        new Actions(driver).dragAndDrop(driver.findElement(drag), driver.findElement(drop)).perform();
        // verify results
        Assert.assertEquals("Drag&Drop failed", 1,driver.findElements(expected).size());
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        By drag = By.id("Item1");
        By drop = By.id("Item5");
        By expected = By.cssSelector("#DragContainer5 #Item1");
        // load page
        driver.get("http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/mk/column2/index.html");
        // wait for draggable element visible
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(drag));
        // drag and drop
        new Actions(driver).dragAndDrop(driver.findElement(drag), driver.findElement(drop)).perform();
        // verify results
        Assert.assertEquals("Drag&Drop failed", 1, driver.findElements(expected).size());
    }
}
```

Any suggestions/pointers on why the above tests are not working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W3C site has HTML5 drag and drop which is currently not supported by Webdriver. Refer to this issue - https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3604

But in your first test case you should have used this for the drag element.
By drag = By.id("drag1");

This is the locator of the image you are dragging.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the open issue in WebDriver. Also, good finding on the invalid locator name on first example test (did not fix the test though due the open issue in WebDriver).